# extremely slow listing with many files

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, nemo

I have an external hard drive formatted as `NTFS`, cotaining a folder with >100 000 small PDFs (max size is 5Mb, and there is 12Gb total size). When trying to navigate into that folder, `Nemo version 3.6.4` hangs (almost) forever. Well, if I am patient enough, it eventually reaches the end, but meanwhile it's not possible to do anything.

In comparison, on Windows 10, opening the folder is instantaneous, and I can immediately browse inside copy/open etc...

I think its a bug. I don't want to boot Windows every time I need to plug in a hard drive

Comment: Three times over the years, I've had NTFS directories with > 10,000 files in them.  Three times, I've had issues with the ACLs, other metadata, the files, or the disk repeatedly becoming corrupted.  My advice would be to entirely avoid this scenario if at all possible.  Even in a Windows-only scenario, I wouldn't do it.  Just my personal experience.  What you're doing is obviously officially supported.

Comment: well it's not me, it's corporate environment. So I can't really fix that

Comment: How long does `ls` take?

Comment: You have described your problem, but not asked a question. What do you want to accomplish?